# solving a cubic equation

Tags: equation-solving

I need to find the minimum $r$ and the maximum $k$ of the following cubic equation for which there does not exist three distinct real roots.

$rx^3-rkx^2+(r+k)x-rk=0$.

Is it possible to find such $r$ and $k$ analytically? Or if you can provide me help using mathematica, that would be fine too.Thanks.

Comment: You could try interpreting the output of `Reduce[Discriminant[r x^3 - r k x^2 + (r + k) x - r k, x] == 0, {r, k}, Reals] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us the approach(es) you've tried?

Comment: The result looks really messy. I could not interpret it. Can you give me the solution?

Comment: I upvoted your question, and then saw your comment _"The result looks really messy. I could not interpret it. Can you give me the solution?"_ Please be aware that if you can't interpret your own problem results, the problem is (perhaps) above your abilities

Comment: You want the cubic polynomial's discriminant to be non-positive for it *not* to have 3 distinct real roots. If you look at the results of what @J.M. suggested, you should at least be able to handle readily some of the boundary cases that arise.

Answer (score 2):

I would leave this as a comment if I could...

You can solve these analytically using some complex analysis and trigonometry as per [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/The_solution_of_cubic_equations).

Also Tristan Needham's excellent *Visual Complex Analysis* deals with solving cubics in depth. I know its not *Mathematica* *per se*, but should be usable along side of it. The trigonometric solution might be a little simpler than what is achieved by the mess that is:

```
Solve[r*x^3 - r*k*x^2 + (r + k)*x - r*k == 0, x]
```

Comment: I agree that it should probably be a comment but I couldn't help upvoting, as I think it's an interesting point.  For specific irreducible cubics, you can often (always??) express the roots in this form using `ComplexExpand`.  For example: `ComplexExpand[Re[z /. Solve[z^3 - 3 z - 1 == 0, z]]]`.  In this case, the `Re` simply removes the imaginary parts, which we know to be zero anyway.